# How to dynamically reference Previous Quarter in Dax (Power BI)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a list of items in a table and want to be able to reference a date in the table and insert a text value to say if that date is "Completed in Current Quarter" or "Completed in Previous Quarter".

I have got the first part to work as the first AND statement works fine, but the 2nd and Statement that contains "=PREVIOUSQUARTER" errors.

If anyone could show me where i am going wrong that would be great.

```
#Completion_Title = SWITCH(TRUE(),
    AND([#Story_Close_Date]>STARTOFQUARTER(DevOps_All_User_Stories[#Current_Date].[Date]),[#Story_Close_Date]<>BLANK()),"Completed in Current Quarter",
    AND([#Story_Close_Date]=PREVIOUSQUARTER(DevOps_All_User_Stories[#Current_Date].[Date]),[#Story_Close_Date]<>BLANK()),"Completed in Previous Quarter"
)
```

Comment: Check this- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/previousquarter-function-dax

Comment: PREVIOUSQUARTER returns a column of dates, not just one value, that's the error. You might try to use the IN operator [#Story_Close_Date] IN PREVIOUSQUARTER(.....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that for [#Story_Close_Date] before the start of the previous quarter the return value should be BLANK(), this should work

```
#Completion_Title =
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    AND(
        [#Story_Close_Date]
            >= STARTOFQUARTER( DevOps_All_User_Stories[#Current_Date].[Date] ),
        [#Story_Close_Date] <> BLANK()
    ), "Completed in Current Quarter",
    AND(
        [#Story_Close_Date]
            >= STARTOFQUARTER(
                PREVIOUSQUARTER( DevOps_All_User_Stories[#Current_Date].[Date] )
            ),
        [#Story_Close_Date] <> BLANK()
    ), "Completed in Previous Quarter"
)
```

I changed the strict "greater than" operator in the condition, since I assume that a completion on the first day of the current quarter belongs to the current quarter, but this is not the point. What matters is that PREVIOUSQUARTER is a time intelligence funcion that returns a table with a single column, containing all the dates of the current selection moved back to the previous quarter. Therefore there might be more than one row.
The STARTOFQUARTER function is also a time intelligence function, that returns a table with one column of dates. But this function only returns one row, and DAX is able to automatically convert a single row, single column table to a scalar value.